# How two bind the selected property of two checkboxes vice versa in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I have given two checkboxes: `checkboxDeSelectAll` and `checkboxSelectAllNotMandatories`

Now I want them to bind that way, that if the user checks one of them than the other is unchecked automatically.

This code

```
checkboxDeSelectAll.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(checkboxSelectAllNotMandatories.selectedProperty());
```

doesn't work. If I select one, the other is selected as well.

Can I make something like the opposite?

```
checkboxDeSelectAll.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(checkboxSelectAllNotMandatories.selectedProperty().not());
```

Does not work.. :/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not use radio buttons?

Comment: because it should be possible to unselect both of them! It's not "either a or b" it is "a or b or none of them".

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes sense...

Comment: I think you can use `ToggleButton`s in a toggle group. This would give you the same functionality, but the UI would look different. Presumably you can use some CSS to make a toggle button look like a check box (or radio button), but it might be easier just to register two listeners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do this with listeners, as far as I am aware:

```
checkboxDeSelectAll.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        checkboxSelectAllNotMandatories.setSelected(false);
    }
});

checkboxSelectAllNotMandatories.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        checkboxDeSelectAll.setSelected(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am wondering why there isn't a possibilty of negation, or something like a deselectedProperty or something like that..

Comment: Bindings are really just a convenience for adding listeners. Adding a second property that was entirely determined by the first would be redundant (just consume additional memory in the vast majority of cases). A bidirectional binding to a function of a property is only possible if the function is bijective: so it works in this case, because `x -> ! x` in bijective, but it's quite hard to write a reasonable API in which you can either verify or even assume that (just try writing an API that works). (You can do it in this specific case, i.e. booleans with not, but the general case doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Like James_D I'd also just take listeners. And if you want to save some lines of code, you might want to write it this way:

```
    Stream.of(fxCb01, fxCb02).forEach(cb -> cb.selectedProperty().addListener((obsVal, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if (cb.isSelected()) {
            CheckBox otherCb = (cb == fxCb01) ? fxCb02 : fxCb01;
            otherCb.setSelected(false);
        }
    }));
```

And if you really want save some keystrokes, you could even replase `cb.isSelected()` by `newVal`.

I'm not sure, which is more readable. It's just a matter of taste.